# removing file extension with htaccess failing

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm using an htaccess script trying to remove the .php  testing the .htaccess on a testing server it runs fine, but on the live server that is a different host it trys rewriting the file based on the absolute path and the rewrite fails

here is the htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

this is taking a url like this www.example.com/services
and trying to point it to /n/c/example.com/public/service.php

I know the {REQUEST_FILENAME} is suppose to be pulling the full local system path, but i don't understand why it's not finding the file. i know very little about htaccess and mod_rewriting so i'm not really sure what I should try to make it base everything off of just the url path, or if there is a better solution. I'm really open to suggestions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try adding `/` before `$1`: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php`

Comment: hmm strange, it loads the correct page but it changes the url to look like this example.com//service.php/

Comment: OK, try `RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]` then

Comment: great, that worked!. Just for future knowledge, could you possible explain what exactly is happening? 

thanks again for the help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]`

It is hard to tell why your rule did not worked for you by having so little info about your Apache setup and any other rewrite rules that you may have.

Quite possible that the `[L]` flag did the trick for you -- you may have other rewrite rules that were rewriting this URL further, producing incorrect result in the end. I don't think that `%{REQUEST_URI}` did such a big job on its own, unless you have some symbolic links / aliases or even some transparent proxy in use which could make a difference.

Keep in mind, that the rules you have shown in your question cannot generate this sort of URL to be visible in browser's address bar (`example.com//service.php/`) -- it has to be a redirect (3xx code) involved .. which suggests that you have other rules somewhere.

Most likely it is a combination of your Apache specific settings & combined rewrite rules logic (where the `L` flag can make a big difference depending on those other rules).

The only way to give more precise answer will be enabling rewrite debugging and analyzing how rewrite was executed and what was involved.

Comment: Thanks, for the info. I'm mainly a front end guy, so apache and server configs go way over my head sometimes. I'll have to do some more research on the topic and see if I can figure out exactly whats going on. Again thanks for the help I Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled mod_rewrite on the other server?  AddModule mod_rewrite, I think.

Also - more likely - have you enabled .htaccess?  You would need to have

```
AllowOverride All
```

or

```
AllowOverride FileInfo
```

for that.

These directives will need to go in the apache config files (usually /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf or one of the files in /etc/httpd/conf.d), and you will need to restart apache to get them to take effect.

Comment: It is allowing me to remove www or force a back slash so i'm going to guess yes, unless those to operations are completely different in terms of apache. Is there a way I can check to see if they are on?  The live environment is on a shared host so I don't actually have access to the apache config files. I did forget to mention that i'm wrapping it in a <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>